# Images stacking instead of floating since changing them to an css sprite

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-sprites

Ive been converting a lot of my site to sprites to speed it up.
Once i switched a heap of images to a sprite that are in a marquee through css, they aren't floating left anymore but are stacked instead.

Its got be baffled to what the issue is.

Any ideas?
http://jsfiddle.net/j7k4f8x7/

```
<p class="microsoft marquee">  <span><a href="hd-tropical-island-beach-paradise-wallpapers.htm"><img class="a1"></img></a>
<a href="hd-garfield-and-friends-comic-desktop-wallpapers.htm"><img class="a2"></img></a>
<a href="the-legend-of-zelda-majora%27s-mask-desktop-wallpapers-3ds.htm"><img class="a3"></img></a>
<a href="hd-disney-frozen-wallpapers-for-mobile-phones-1080x1920.htm"><img class="a4"></img></a>
<a href="hd-penguins-of-madagascar-mobile-wallpapers-1080x1920.htm"><img class="a5"></img></a>
<a href="the-augusta-national-golf-course-wallpapers-hd.htm"><img class="a6"></img></a>
<a href="banjo-kazooie-wallpapers-hd-nuts-and-bolts-and-nintendo-64.htm"><img class="a7"></img></a>
<a href="the-legend-of-zelda-twilight-princess-hd-wallpapers-skyward-sword.htm"><img class="a8"></img></a>
<a href="vw-combi-van-hd-wallpapers-volkswagen-hippie-bus.htm"><img class="a9"></img></a>
<a href="monsters-inc-backgrounds-and-monsters-university-wallpapers-hd.htm"><img class="a10"></img></a>
<a href="awesome-minecraft-hd-desktop-wallpapers-1080p-backgrounds-1920x1080.htm"><img class="a11"></img></a>
<a href="despicable-me-2-hd-wallpapers-for-desktop-1920x1080.htm"><img class="a12"></img></a>
<a href="toy-story-1-2-3-wallpapers-hd-1920x1080-backgrounds.htm"><img class="a13"></img></a>
<a href="the-avengers-wallpapers-for-desktop-1920x1080-movie-backgrounds.htm"><img class="a14"></img></a>
<a href="1920x1080-funny-backgrounds-hilarious-wallpapers-for-desktop.htm"><img class="a15"></img></a></span></p>

.a1, .a2, .a3, .a4, .a5, .a6, .a7, .a9, .a10, .a11, .a12, .a13, .a14, .a15
{width:100px; height:58px;
background-image: url('http://www.techagesite.com/scroll-sprite.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
float: left;}


.a1 {background-position: 0px 0px;}
.a2 {background-position: 0px -64px;}
.a3 {background-position: 0px -128px;}
.a4 {background-position: 0px -186px;}
.a5 {background-position: 0px -244px;}
.a6 {background-position: 0px -302px;}
.a7 {background-position: 0px -366px;}
.a8 {background-position: 0px -424px;}
.a9 {background-position: 0px -482px;}
.a10 {background-position: 0px -540px;}
.a11 {background-position: 0px -598px;}
.a12 {background-position: 0px -656px;}
.a13 {background-position: 0px -714px;}
.a14 {background-position: 0px -772px;}
.a15 {background-position: 0px -830px;}

.marquee {
    width: 235px;

float:left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px green solid;

}

.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    text-indent: 0;
    animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;

}
.marquee span:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }



.microsoft {
    z-index: 1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 2em; height: 2em;

}
```

Comment: you want it horizontally arranged?

Comment: Yes. It was before i changed to sprites.

Comment: AnyOne have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add below code to your CSS

```
a{
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Working:Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j7k4f8x7/2/)

**OR**

Remove **float:left** from (just as @Usman Arshad said)

```
.a1, .a2, .a3, .a4, .a5, .a6, .a7, .a9, .a10, .a11, .a12, .a13, .a14, .a15 {
    width:100px;
    height:58px;
    background-image: url('http://www.techagesite.com/scroll-sprite.png'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Ive tried it on my page and it doesn't work. The fiddle does but not my page. All i get is a green border line about a pixel high and its specified width when removing the float and about 10px high with its specified width with option one. Option one still shows nothing inside the marquee though.

Comment: Got it working but now the div that sits to the right of it is now underneath. How can i fix this? http://jsfiddle.net/15qbxame/2/

Comment: You had two .right-column1 class(at top and bottom in your CSS), rewritten to one, and modified some lines, like removed clear:both; also added red border just to check your Error Div position. http://jsfiddle.net/15qbxame/4/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float: left;` from code.

Check attached snippet demo.

```css
.a1, .a2, .a3, .a4, .a5, .a6, .a7, .a9, .a10, .a11, .a12, .a13, .a14, .a15
{width:100px; height:58px;
background-image: url('http://www.techagesite.com/scroll-sprite.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.a1 {background-position: 0px 0px;}
.a2 {background-position: 0px -64px;}
.a3 {background-position: 0px -128px;}
.a4 {background-position: 0px -186px;}
.a5 {background-position: 0px -244px;}
.a6 {background-position: 0px -302px;}
.a7 {background-position: 0px -366px;}
.a8 {background-position: 0px -424px;}
.a9 {background-position: 0px -482px;}
.a10 {background-position: 0px -540px;}
.a11 {background-position: 0px -598px;}
.a12 {background-position: 0px -656px;}
.a13 {background-position: 0px -714px;}
.a14 {background-position: 0px -772px;}
.a15 {background-position: 0px -830px;}

.marquee {
    width: 235px;

float:left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px green solid;

}

.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    text-indent: 0;
    animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;

}
.marquee span:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }



.microsoft {
    z-index: 1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 2em; height: 2em;

}
```

```html
<p class="microsoft marquee">  <span><a href="hd-tropical-island-beach-paradise-wallpapers.htm"><img class="a1"></img></a>
<a href="hd-garfield-and-friends-comic-desktop-wallpapers.htm"><img class="a2"></img></a>
<a href="the-legend-of-zelda-majora%27s-mask-desktop-wallpapers-3ds.htm"><img class="a3"></img></a>
<a href="hd-disney-frozen-wallpapers-for-mobile-phones-1080x1920.htm"><img class="a4"></img></a>
<a href="hd-penguins-of-madagascar-mobile-wallpapers-1080x1920.htm"><img class="a5"></img></a>
<a href="the-augusta-national-golf-course-wallpapers-hd.htm"><img class="a6"></img></a>
<a href="banjo-kazooie-wallpapers-hd-nuts-and-bolts-and-nintendo-64.htm"><img class="a7"></img></a>
<a href="the-legend-of-zelda-twilight-princess-hd-wallpapers-skyward-sword.htm"><img class="a8"></img></a>
<a href="vw-combi-van-hd-wallpapers-volkswagen-hippie-bus.htm"><img class="a9"></img></a>
<a href="monsters-inc-backgrounds-and-monsters-university-wallpapers-hd.htm"><img class="a10"></img></a>
<a href="awesome-minecraft-hd-desktop-wallpapers-1080p-backgrounds-1920x1080.htm"><img class="a11"></img></a>
<a href="despicable-me-2-hd-wallpapers-for-desktop-1920x1080.htm"><img class="a12"></img></a>
<a href="toy-story-1-2-3-wallpapers-hd-1920x1080-backgrounds.htm"><img class="a13"></img></a>
<a href="the-avengers-wallpapers-for-desktop-1920x1080-movie-backgrounds.htm"><img class="a14"></img></a>
<a href="1920x1080-funny-backgrounds-hilarious-wallpapers-for-desktop.htm"><img class="a15"></img></a></span></p>
```